# sudo port install cmake trouble (for MGTwitterEngine)

Tags: iphone, twitter, terminal, cmake, mgtwitterengine

I am following [This Tutorial](http://damienh.org/2009/06/20/setting-up-mgtwitterengine-with-yajl-106-for-iphone-development/) on installing MGTwitterEngine on my MAC osx 10.6.2.

I am stuck on this step:
**sudo port install cmake**

it gives me the following error:

```
dlopen(/opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    while executing
"load /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib"
    ("package ifneeded Pextlib 1.0" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Pextlib 1.0"
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 40)
Rex-MacBook-Pro:~ Rex$
```

Thus, I cannot use TERMINAL to install YAJL to get my app to build. Help needed.

P.S.

- In terminal preferences, **Shells Open With** is either /usr/bin/login or /bin/bash
- YAJL is supposedly installed at /Users/Rex
- I am using OSX 10.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was that my OS is snow leopard and the version of Xcode i was using was not. Re-installing the proper xcode update solved it.